# Populate form textBox with a string from another application

Tags: forms, web-applications

I thought I could simplify my specific question telling I wanted to populate a text field on a form with the output of a bar code reader. Searching on the net I learnt the bar code reader can act like the keyboard and put the text on the field which has focus.

Unfortunately my needs are slightly different. I need to put inside a form textbox the code of a specific rfid which is in the range of the rfid reader connected to the host. I don't have a button to trigger the rfid detection but only an application which shows a list of them.
Is there a better method than cut&paste for moving the text string associated to a Rfid from the application to the web form ? I wrote the application which connects to the reader, so I suppose I can put a button which writes the chosen string to standard input, like the trigger of the bar code reader, but this way the input field has not the focus, so it is worthless. 
How can I achieve my goal ?

Update for clarify and simplify my question.

I don' want any direct interaction with the rfid reader and the form or the web server.
I have an application which shows a list of string (in my case they are rfid related, but it is not important). I would like to push a button on the application or on the web form and populate an input field on the form with one of those strings. Don't know nothing about browser plug-ins, perhaps I could do one which mimic what the application does...That way the web form should interact with the plug-in to retrieve the data...

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: Maybe you could add some information about the technologies your are using and the how the systems are connected. Is there a way to retrieve the data from the reader within your website, for instance wating on a event via web sockets or polling the server regularly?

Comment: I have dll for different languages which expose the same interface for interacting with the reader. On the client host I must have an application which shows the rfid in the range of the reader. I don't want any direct interaction between the server and the reader. I'm looking for an easy way to move a string form the application to the web form besides cut&paste.

Comment: please try to improve on the structure of your question and including any code you have to clarify.

Comment: tried to clarify my question with an update